# Unable to convert arrays into IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I wrote a method that has the following signature:

```
Task<EmailMessageActivity[]> SearchMessagesAsync(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<SearchLogicalOperator, IEnumerable<SearchCriteria>>> filterConditions, int limit = 20, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

I also wrote the following unit test for this method:

```
// Arrange
var filterConditions = new KeyValuePair<SearchLogicalOperator, SearchCriteria[]>[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<SearchLogicalOperator, SearchCriteria[]>(SearchLogicalOperator.Or, new [] { new SearchCriteriaEqual("field1", "value1"), new SearchCriteriaEqual("field2", "value2") }),
    new KeyValuePair<SearchLogicalOperator, SearchCriteria[]>(SearchLogicalOperator.And, new [] { new SearchCriteriaEqual("field3", "value3"), new SearchCriteriaEqual("field4", "value4") }),
};

// Act
var result = await emailActivities.SearchMessagesAsync(filterConditions, limit, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Unfortunately, Visual Studio reports the following problem in my unit test:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 
'KeyValuePair<SearchLogicalOperator, SearchCriteria[]>[]' to 
'IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<SearchLogicalOperator, IEnumerable<SearchCriteria>>>'
```

I'm confused why VS.NET is unable to convert the arrays into enumerations.

Comment: The problem here is the inner `SearchCriteria[]` to `IEnumerable<SearchCriteria>` conversion.

Comment: Maybe good to add is that `IEnumerable<out T>` marked with `out` while `KeyValuePair<TK,TV>` is not (covariance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this? Problem may be leads from array is type of IEnumarable but it is not IEnumarable<>.

```
var filterConditions = new List<KeyValuePair<SearchLogicalOperator, IEnumerable<SearchCriteria>>>
                       {
                           new KeyValuePair<SearchLogicalOperator, IEnumerable<SearchCriteria>>(SearchLogicalOperator.Or, new List<SearchCriteria> { new SearchCriteriaEqual("field1", "value1"), new SearchCriteriaEqual("field2", "value2") }),
                           new KeyValuePair<SearchLogicalOperator, IEnumerable<SearchCriteria>>(SearchLogicalOperator.And, new List<SearchCriteria>{ new SearchCriteriaEqual("field3", "value3"), new SearchCriteriaEqual("field4", "value4") }),
                       };

// Act
var result = await emailActivities.SearchMessagesAsync(filterConditions, limit, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: I get the same `cannot convert` exception in visual studio

Comment: I am happy to help :)